# Libre Office UI Colours

Tags: macos, libreoffice

I have Libre Office 5.3.6.1 installed on my MacBook running macOS 10.13 (although it behaved similarly on earlier releases).

Unfortunately it is almost unusable as most of the buttons have a Dark Blue background, making it almost impossible to read the black text.

I have searched through most of the preferences, but can't seem to find any way to change this.

Is there any way of changing this.

This seems to be influenced by the Mac `System Preferences/General/Appearance` but this offers only Blue and Graphite (which is even worse), but other Applications seem to use more reasonable colours.

Answer (score 0):

I was checking my LibreOffice, which is working without a problem. It's under Linux, but I guess there might be a match with your one because it is 5.1 above.

So was checking my settings, in - Tools options. All my settings in view section are as follows:

[image]

Also try checking the customization section.

Comment: Does this really answer the question? It seems there are no color-related settings in your screenshot. If I'm wrong then please tell us which exact option can help the OP.

Comment: Well man, as i said, my F*^king Libre Office is working, so I'm sharing what is it actualy, so if it is possible to make it work, for the other guy, or lady, or what ever . Color-related settings, i don't even know how to put colors in my document, I'm just typing. And i don't know what the OP abrev means. Can you anlight me ?         Thank you !

Comment: Have a nice day!

Comment: Do you have a better idea ? Give it a try!